# 1.5 hrs transfer at DXB - Can I make it?

Tags: air-travel, airport-transfer, emirates, dxb

I booked a flight from COK to BOS, ticket sold by Emirates (both legs are operated by Emirates). There is a 90 minutes layover at DXB, where I have to change flights. My question is, can I make it? In the digital ticket that Emirates emailed me, they show a suggested check-in time of 05:20 for the second flight, but my first flight only lands there at 06:50! Because Emirates sold this as one ticket and because a majority of Emirates' flights go through DXB, I'm assuming it'll be fine, but I thought I'd just confirm. 1.5 hrs seems tight to me, but maybe DXB will take less time than AUH (where I've previously traveled through) since there is no US Customs Preclearance.

As a related question, should I collect my bags and check them in again at DXB? What I've heard is that as long as the ticket was sold as one by the airline, they'll take care of your bags. Is that true?

Comment: If it's in a single ticket and both legs are operated by Emirates, you'll be fine and the bags will be checked through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You'll be fine.** Since you're connecting Emirates to Emirates, you don't need to go through immigration or check in, you can just walk directly to your next gate with a quick security check at most.  All Emirates flights land at Terminal 3 so transfers are straightforward, although you may be in for a bit of a walk, since it's a *very* large building!  And yes, your bags will also be checked through to your final destination.

In the unlikely event of missing your connection (first leg badly delayed etc), Emirates will put you and your bags on the next available flight.

Comment: That's great! I assumed it would be okay (Emirates would know better than to sell connections that no one can make), but I didn't know that the transfer process would be as simple as walking from one gate to another. When I transferred through AUH I had quite a big security check and an immigration check, but that could be because of US Preclearance, since I could just walk out of the airport when I landed in the US without doing any immigration there. Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: @Zo-Bro-23 Yes, Abu Dhabi was different because you were flying to the US and they have preclearance there.  This is not the case for Dubai, so you'll get to enjoy US immigration only on arrival in Boston.